# Time Series Forecasting Right Metric

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting

I'm doing a time series forecasting using `Exponential Weighted Moving Average`, as a baseline model. I'm wondering on what would be the best metric to use if I have a set of percentage values.

Is it okay to use `RMSE` to assess model's performance?

Here's the output,

[image: Time Series Forecast]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, RMSE is a very suitable metric for you.

Follow the blogs on machinelearningmastery.com
This guy has written some very good blogs about time-series predictions and you will learn a lot from them.

Example blog for time series forecasting:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/time-series-prediction-lstm-recurrent-neural-networks-python-keras/

Example blog for loss function selection:

https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-choose-loss-functions-when-training-deep-learning-neural-networks/